# Generating all gapped k-mer sequences from string

Tags: r, string

I am interested in making all gapped-kmers from a sequence, with gapped-kmer defined as a sequence of length k separated by up to m positions from another sequence of length k. So for example, "sequence CAGAT the gappy pair
kernel with k = 1 and m = 2 finds pairs of monomers with zero to two irrelevant positions in between. i.e. it finds the features CA, C.G, C..A, AG, A.A, A..T, GA, G.T and AT"

```
replacefxn <- function(x, k, m) {
  substr(x, k + 1, k + m) <- paste(rep("X", m), collapse = "")
  return(x)
}
gappedkmersfxn <- function(x, k, m) {
  n <- (2 * k + m)
  subseq <-
    substring(x, seq(from = 1, to = (nchar(x) - n + 1)), seq(from = n, to = nchar(x)))
  return(sapply(subseq, replacefxn, k, m))
}



allgappedkmersfxn <- function(x, k, m) {
  kmers <- list()
  for (i in 0:m) {
    kmers[[i]] <- gappedkmersfxn(x, k, i)
  }
  kmers <- unlist(kmers)
  return(kmers)
}
```

`allgappedkmersfxn` is how I have it implemented currently, but it does not add the features with no gap (m is maximum gap, but goes from 0 to m), thus not giving me all of the desired features (see example of "CAGAT"). In addition, it is very slow and inefficient when doing millions of sequences at a time. It is also coded poorly, but with limited experience in R I am not sure how to improve it.

What would the most efficient way of doing this be while making sure that all expected subsequences (ex: CAGAT -> CA, C.G, C..A, AG, A.A, A..T, GA, G.T and AT for k=1, m=2) are included in the output?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to look at the implementation of a gappy pair kernel in the [Bioconductor kebabs package](http://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/kebabs.html).

Installation:

```
## try http:// if https:// URLs are not supported
source("https://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite("kebabs")
```

To generate a k = 1, m = 2 kernel:

```
library(kebabs)
gappyK1M2 <- gappyPairKernel(k = 1, m = 2)
```

To generate an explicit representation from a DNA sequence:

```
dnaseqs <- DNAStringSet("CAGAT")
dnaseqsrep <- getExRep(dnaseqs, gappyK1M2)
```

The k-mers are stored in the `Dimnames` slot:

```
dnaseqsrep@Dimnames[[2]]
[1] "A.A"  "AG"   "AT"   "A..T" "CA"   "C..A" "C.G"  "GA"   "G.T"
```